# Deleted *answers* which are improved

Tags: support, answers, deleted-answers

If a question is low quality then high rep. users have the option to close it, and then later the option to delete it. This has a built-in safeguard, in the sense that if the question is closed but then edited it is placed in a review queue and may then be re-opened as a result. Great.

So what happens to low quality *answers*. High rep. users can only vote to delete these; there is no concept of a "put on-hold" answer.

> Is a deleted answer "lost" even when it is edited and improved, or is there a *automated* system in place, similar to that for low-quality questions but which is only available to 20k users?

[I understand that the editor/answerer can appeal on meta in the appropriate thread. But this is not automated.]

(My motivation for asking this question is: I recently saw a poorly-formatted answer up for deletion in the review queue, and someone had commented about MathJaX. However, the answer was posted 30 mins earlier and the user had not been seen since (which is not unreasonable!). Therefore, they have had no chance to respond to the comment by editing and improving their answer. What would happen if I voted to delete?)

Comment: There's [delete/undelete history/"queue" on Moderator Tools for 10k+](https://math.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days)

Comment: @AndrewT. This doesn't flag answers which have been edited though.

Comment: Since this post seems to be (at least partially) about deletions from review, it is worth mentioning that if a post gets deleted by "recommend deletion" option (rather than by three delete votes) the OP can simply undelete it. See [How can I undelete one of my posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) section in the deletion FAQ and [Answers deleted via Recommend Deletion votes in review should not be undeletable by the answerer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226993#228479).

Comment: You make a good point.  Particularly for new users, if there is an Answer which perhaps can be improved by including more thoughts or better formatting, I encourage the author to self-delete, edit, then undelete.  I have no sense on how successful these comments have been.  As a "high rep" user I then must refrain from voting to delete, so there's an opportunity cost associated with this approach, and I use it sparingly.